# Highlight search term using the indexOf in React

Tags: reactjs, search, highlight, indexof

I have a search component that returns data from slideData based on the searchTerm. My goal is to highlight the word that is typed. I think i need to use indexOf or  tag but I am struggling with the logic of where to use it? For clarity, the expected result is that if i search for "hamburger" it will display all results with hamburger and highlight "hamburger" in those results.

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
```

```
const SlideData = [
  {
    slideIndex: 1,
    title: "My name is Bob",
    text1: "Bob likes to eat hamburgers",
    text2: "Kenny likes to eat hot dogs",
    text3: "Terry likes milkshakes"
  },
  {
    slideIndex: 2,
    title: "My name is Jill",
    text1: "Jill likes to eat hamburgers",
    text2: "Joshua likes to eat hot dogs",
    text3: "Steven likes milkshakes"
  }
]
```

```
<div className="search-results">
          <ul className="search-list">
            {SlideData.filter((item) => {
              if (searchTerm === "") {
                return null;
              } else {
                //concat the text properties into variable//
                let searchText = item.title + item.text1 + item.text2 + item.text3 + item.text4;
                //if the variable contains the search term value//
                if (searchText.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
                  //return those items//
                  return item;
                }
              }
          
            }).map((item) => (
              //map through the items and display list of results
              <div key={item.slideIndex} style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
                <h4 style={{ color: "white" }}>{item.title}</h4>
                <li className="search-item">{item.text1}</li>
                <li className="search-item">{item.text1.indexOf(searchTerm)}</li>
                <a
                  className="search-link"
                  onClick={() => {
                    context.setCurrentSlide(item.slideIndex);
                    setSearchTerm("");
                  }}
                >
                  Go To Slide {item.slideIndex}
                </a>
              </div>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
```

SOMETHING I AM TRYING

```
        //find the search term in the results//
              const highlighted = item.text1.indexOf(searchTerm);
              if(searchTerm === -1){
                //highlight the term
              }else{
                //Do nothing
              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to target the results with different styles you need to break it out to it's own HTML element.

You can use this regex function

```
const splitResult = (result) =>
//Split on search result and then simply style the matches
result.split(new RegExp(`(${searchTerm})`, `gi`)).map((piece, index) => {
  return (
    <span
      key={index}
      style={{
        background:
          piece.toLowerCase() === searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()
            ? "YELLOW"
            : "TRANSPARENT"
      }}
    >
      {piece}
    </span>
  );
});
```

Here's your full component I removed some parts that are not related to the question

```
export default function App() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  const splitResult = (result) =>
    //Split on search result and then simply style the matches then map through
    result.split(new RegExp(`(${searchTerm})`, `gi`)).map((piece, index) => {
      return (
        <span
          key={index}
          style={{
            background:
              piece.toLowerCase() === searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase()
                ? "YELLOW"
                : "TRANSPARENT"
          }}
        >
          {piece}
        </span>
       );
     });

   return (
     <div className="search-results">
       <ul className="search-list">
         {/** Search input */}
         <input
           type="search"
           value={searchTerm}
           onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
         />
         {SlideData.filter((item) => {
           if (searchTerm === "") {
             return null;
           } else {
            //concat the text properties into variable//
             let searchText = item.title + item.text1 + item.text2 + item.text3 + item.text4;
            //if the variable contains the search term value//
            if (searchText.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
               //return those items//
               return item;
            }
          }
          return null;
         }).map((item) => (
          //map through the items and display list of results
          <div key={item.slideIndex} style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
            <h4>{item.title}</h4>
            <li>{splitResult(item.text1)}</li>
            <li>{item.text1.indexOf(searchTerm)}</li>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I see so regExp is what i was looking for! thank you for providing a full answer too, I know it takes more time but its easier to learn through demonstration. Thanks! I will practice this

Comment: to summarize, you passed in the item.text and item.title values into the splitResult function as arguments which  then were split using the split method, basically mapping the searchTerm into "peices" which are styled . the true false checks makes them yellow if they equal the searchterm and transparent if not. am i close?

Comment: @lache Yes except I don't think I was meant to do wrap the title...